# Implementing vertical scroll with css and javascript? (with fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/93/

I have an unordered list of items that can be scrolled through.

I'm trying to work out which approach is best:

1. Use CSS / jquery to set overflow to hidden and move the position of the `<ul>`

What's the best way to do this?

Code:

```
<div class="span4 side-study-box">
            <div class="side-box-menu">
                <a class ="side-box-menu-nav"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-white"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-facetime-video "></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-headphones "></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-hdd"></i></a>
                        <!-- Need code, math, sound, url, text -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a class ="side-box-menu-nav"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/94/

you need to add some type of click binding to move the menu up or down and a view port to limit the size

There are so many options when animating this is a really simple example that works only once. click binding would be like

```
$('.down').click(function () {
    var $move = $('.side-study-box ul');
    $move.css({
        top: '-20px'
    })
})
```

To get the elements posistion using jquery try

```
var position = $move.position();
```

Comment: Thanks Kieran.  What if there are multiple elements to scroll through?  I tried doing something like top: top + 20 but obviously this wouldn't work.

Comment: you would want to get its current position and adjust it by 20px -20 to move up and +20 to move down.